# QtJambi example not executing

Tags: java, archlinux, qt-jambi

I'm trying to compile and run the tooltip code from [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/qtjambi/introduction/). I obtained QtJambi from my package manager (the package is `qtjambi-beta` from AUR), which installed it into the directory `/opt/qtjambi-beta/`. In particular, the `qtjambi-4.7.0.jar` file is located at `/opt/qtjambi-beta/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/qtjambi-4.7.0.jar`.

Now, I made a folder called `qtpractice` and put the example in there under the name `JambiApp.java`. The code I put into it was exactly as follows (following the example I linked):

```
package qtpractice;

import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QApplication;
import com.trolltech.qt.gui.QWidget;

public class JambiApp extends QWidget {

     public JambiApp() {
        setWindowTitle("Tooltip");
        setToolTip("This is QWidget");
        resize(250, 150);
        move(300, 300);
        show();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        QApplication.initialize(args);
        new JambiApp();
        QApplication.exec();
    }
}
```

I compiled it with `javac qtpractice/*.java -cp /opt/qtjambi-beta/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/qtjambi-4.7.0.jar`, which worked fine. I then tried to execute it with `java qtpractice.JambiApp`, and I got the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class qtpractice.JambiApp
```

EDIT: Based on some advice from the comments, I tried this command instead: `java -cp /opt/qtjambi-beta/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/qtjambi-4.7.0.jar qtpractice.JambiApp`
. When I did this, I got the following error again:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class qtpractice.JambiApp
```

What did I miss? From what I can tell, I did everything necessary to make it execute.

Comment: You need to give same `-cp` args to `java` command too. That’s common Java practice.

Comment: @Smar: Tried that - same error exactly.

Comment: Please add the whole command line and error to your question.

Comment: You need to add the native jar to execution command too (it’s not required for compilation).

Comment: @Smar: What do you mean by the 'native jar'?

Comment: There should be jar which name is `qtjambi-native-linux64-gcc-4.8.6.jar` or similar, or something with `linux32` `linux64`, depending of how old that version is. Could you give name of that jar so I could make proper answer? :)

Comment: @Smar It is ``qtjambi-linux64-gcc-4.7.0.jar``.

Comment: Okay, answered. Sorry for late response, I was at work and forgot about the question :) I hope the thing worked for you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all jars Qt Jambi needs in classpath.

This can be done on CLI with command similar to

```
java -cp /opt/qtjambi-beta/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/qtjambi-4.7.0.jar:/opt/qtjambi-beta/qtjambi-linux64-community-4.7.0/qtjambi-linux64-gcc-4.7.0.jar:. qtpractice.JambiApp
```

When compiling, native jar does not need to be present, as the native libraries are just for Jambi classes to be able to use Qt.

Comment: Also a further note - I tried doing this in Eclipse, and it worked fine. However, I don't really want to use an IDE (and I don't get how it does all this stuff anyway), and this has me really mystified, so I'd like to figure out what the hell is going on.

Comment: Well, then give the full error (what the command returned when you ran it)

Comment: ``Error: Could not find or load main class qtpractice.JambiApp``

Comment: that’s *all* it returned?

Comment: I'm as mystified as you are.

Comment: Ohh... I think I got it. When you’re running with classpath, current directory is not in classpath by default. So if the class you’re running the file from current directory, you need to add :. to end of the classpath. I’ll update the answer.